# Why are asymptotic expansions not common for solving partial and algebraic differential equations?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, asymptotics

There are many different numerical methods for solving partial and algebraic differential equations. The common commercial and open source packages (e.g. [Elmer](https://www.csc.fi/web/elmer) and OpenFOAM) use discretization/meshing based methods such as finite difference or finite volume.

When I was in undergrad we used to use power series for this matter all the time. They have several advantages over other methods:

1. The result is easily differentiable/integratable
2. They seem to be computationally less expensive (the solution can be found analytically/symbolically)
3. Complicated boundary and initial conditions can be applied easily (like moving objects)
4. No meshing is required
5. solutions are reusable, only the boundary/initial conditions need to be applied

However, It is a surprise that there are not many proprietary or open source software implementing this algorithms. At least I haven't seen much. The only thing I have seen so far is the Mathematica's `AsymptoticDSolveValue` function, which is only for ODEs.

Now my question is why asymptotic methods are not as common for solving nonlinear differential equations. Are there any scientific studies showing they are less efficient than common methods? Maybe there are some products and I am not aware of them. If that's the case I would appreciate if you could let me know.

**P.S.1.** There are other series too:

- Chebyshev polynomials
- Padé rational functions approximant
- Lagrange interpolation
- Laurent series
- Fourier series

to mention some.

**P.S.2.** Other relevant topics: [Frobenius method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_method), [WKB approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WKB_approximation), [Spectral method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_method), Finite element method

Comment: I think that is a good question. I think it may be too complicated.

Comment: @mick you mean the answer to my question or asymptotic methods in general?

Comment: Well If you keep one variable fixed , you end up with a simpler equation. But that Also implies not keeping it fixed must give a “ meta solution “.

Comment: @mick what do you mean? Would you please elaborate?

Comment: I'm not sure what the question is to be honest? If, by asymptotic methods, you mean expanding a function in terms of some orthogonal basis then I would tell you that it is a very common approach. Finite differencing is probably the most commonly used approach because historically it has been used extensively, it is  easy to implement and because it still gives reasonably good approximations.

Comment: @Mattos It seems that the term asymptotic methods has caused [some confusion](https://www.reddit.com/r/math/comments/932b3f/why_asymptotic_methods_are_not_common_for_solving/e3ac3f5). I used it because of the Mathematica guys (see [this](http://blog.wolfram.com/2018/07/19/getting-to-the-point-asymptotic-expansions-in-the-wolfram-language/)). If you could suggest a better term, I will edit the post.

Comment: @Mattos These methods have indeed been used a lot, but they are not as common as FEM and CFD methods. There no implementations of these methods which I am aware of. My question is why? is there any reason why they are not being used in common numerical PDE solvers?

Comment: Some E&M problems can be solved asymptotically with the 'shooting and bouncing' method (essentially ray optics) in the high-frequency limit.  You miss certain phenomena, like creeping waves.  I view analytic solutions as a useful check on numerics.  Real-world problems rarely reduce to spheres, boxes, and cones.

Comment: @skbmoore I'm not familiar with all the terminology you are using. How about you elaborate on that in an answer below?

Comment: @Foad I think you're confused. The phrase 'they are not as common as FEM and CFD methods' doesn't make sense at all. CFD stands for computational fluid dynamics, _any_ numerical method that yields an accurate solution would be considered a CFD method. Finite differencing and expansion in terms of orthogonal basis functions are two different numerical approaches to computing a solution. FEM is a way of dealing with complex geometries by splitting your domain into subdomains and then solving the problem in each subdomain _any way you can_, including using basis functions or finite differencing.

Comment: @Mattos You are absolutely right. CFD is not a PDE solving method and I shouldn't have mentioned it. What I ,meant was the finite volume methods  which are mostly prevalent in the CFD applications. Also I think FEM is very similar to the Spectral method by nature and shouldn't have been mentioned as well.

Comment: @Foad E&M= Electricity and Magnetism.  I'm thinking of Maxwell's partial differential equations.  To find a high frequency solution in complex geometries, you can can try an asymptotic solution such as the program 'Xpatch' attempts.  Google 'Xpatch' to find more information.

Answer (score 7):

This question is very broad, and its answers subjective (how do you quantify usefulness?), but I can give some comments.

**1. Asymptotic convergence is not broadly guaranteed *a priori*.**

When solving an [elliptic PDE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_operator) using the [finite element method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_element_method), there are well-established results such as the [Lax-Milgram theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Lax-MilgramTheorem.html) and [Cea's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%C3%A9a%27s_lemma) that furnish straightforward "guarantees" of solving efficiency for such a problem. This is nice because the validity of such theorems depends only on the nature of the equation, not of the solution.

Compare that with, say, trying to obtain a Taylor series representation of a PDE solution over some expansion point. Who says the function is analytic over the whole domain? And estimating the radius of convergence with something like the [Cauchy-Hadamard theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Hadamard_theorem) requires informed guesses as to the behavior of the coefficients of such a series, which are themselves obtained from solution attempts.

You often get the same problem in perturbation theory; who says that a matched boundary layer approach or WKB approach will yield a convergent series? Often perturbation expansions of this type rely on constructing a sequence of linear operator equations out of a single nonlinear operator equation, and hoping that your sequence of equations has a solution up to some order (as determined by the [Fredholm alternative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fredholm_alternative), or other such theorems). This involves getting rid of [terms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secular_variation) that are incompatible with these operators as they appear in the solution sequences, which is a fairly unpredictable process. As I understand it, there are very few theorems that guarantee convergence of such series without having *some* information about the solution.

**2. Asymptotic methods are fundamentally local.**

Series approaches involving [orthogonal function sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_Fourier_series) (Fourier series, Chebyshev polynomials) use the geometry of [Lebesgue spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lp_space) to make guarantees about the "goodness" of the approximation: for example, that the $L^2$ norm of the residual always decreases as you increase the terms in the series, [that the series is the best representation of the function in a specific subspace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_projection_theorem), etc. This is due to the fact that such series are approximating the function globally, whereas asymptotic methods approach solutions locally. As a result, there are few such broad, general guarantees in asymptotic series, which can show weird divergent behaviors in specific regions of the domain as terms in the approximation increase even if it behaves perfectly well near the point of local expansion.

The strange behaviors of asymptotic series are, for me, epitomized by [Carrier's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/George_F._Carrier#Carrier%27s_Rule): "Divergent series converge faster than convergent series because they don't have to converge".

**3. It is difficult to predict the computational efficiency and solvability of algorithmic asymptotic methods.**

Because asymptotic methods are local and have few *a priori* guarantees of behaving "well", it is very difficult to predict whether an algorithm employing such methods terminates or, if it does, how quickly it would do so. Consider, in perhaps a naive way, an algorithm attempting an asymptotic expansion that must match some boundary condition in a region far from the expansion point, and the algorithm terminates when the approximation is within some error margin. It may well be the case that no such expansion of the type you want exists (à la [Stokes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stokes%27_paradox) or Whitehead paradox), and as a result your algorithm keeps fruitlessly searching for the right function *ad infinitum*.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. There are many terminologies that I am not familiar with. So I need more study to be able to comment, but the moment: "how do you quantify usefulness?" I think computational efficiency. What is the convergence rate versus computational resources (i.e CPU time)

Comment: I'll add some information to the answer regarding computational complexity shortly.

Comment: I posted a follow up question [here](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/95886/algorithm-for-using-power-series-to-numerically-solve-a-partial-differential-equ) I would appreciate if you could take a look.